# Amplifying Millivolts with a Single Power Supply Op Amp in a Large Gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, low-power, instrumentation-amplifier

I have a signal  around 1mV-10mV to be amplified. This signal should be fed into an ADC (ADS1115 ) which has minimum full scale range of 0.256V. So the gain should be at least around 300. I am thinking of doing this amplification with a single supply (5V) low power Op-amp. I went through some op amps (OPA, LM) and can't find if they are good enough as some don't have libraries to simulate and most are out of  stock in our area.
I would like to know if it is possible to achieve such a gain with an acceptable accuracy (error level 5~10%) and some suggestions of particular op amp models.
Couldn't find an ADC which has lower than 0.256V full scale range, seeking for suggestions if you have any, so I wouldn't have to amplify the signals in a large factor.

Comment: There are a number of ADCs that might be suitable. A common application is load cells where the values are in the microvolt range.  A sigma-delta converter is normally used and these can be around 24 bit resolution.

Comment: A 10mV signal into 256mV range would be a gain of 25.6, not 300. That is very reasonable for an opamp.

Comment: @user1850479 when it is around 1mV it has to be 256 which I roughly said as 300.

Comment: @Kartman I am not familiar with sigma-delta converters and went through some datasheets too. I couldn't find what was their lowest detectable voltage. Could you tell me if there is a particular term for ADCs for the lowest detectable voltage except minimum full scale range. So as your suggestion, would I be able to use a sigma delta converter directly without using an op amp measure my mentioned voltage range (1mV-10mV)

Comment: The point of the ADC is that it must have high resolution. Any 24 bit ADC is probably going to be sigma delta. The ADC converts an analog voltage into a number which can be anywhere from 0 to 2^n - 1 where n is the number of bits. So if your reference voltage is 3.3V, the inherent resolution (ignoring noise or inaccuracies) is 3.3/2^n. If n is 24, that is 3.3/16.8 million. So like 0.2 microvolt steps. Of course there is also noise and some inaccuracy. But this should be a viable approach.

Comment: @mkeith Yes, I understand that part. My problem is even though the step size is like 0.2 microvolts as you mentioned, won't there be a lower detectable voltage limit which is greater than the step size. In another way, if we apply a voltage of 0.2uV, is it detectable by the ADC if we neglect all the practical imperfections.

Comment: Maybe not one lsb. But maybe you could read to 1 or 2 uV, assuming a nice quiet and steady reference, and good filtering on the ADC input. This is a bit more precise than any ADC I have worked with. So I am stretching a bit beyond my practical experience. I know for a fact that thermocouple voltages can be directly converted to temperature with reasonable accuracy using a 24 bit ADC (see labjack). You could probably save a lot of time if you just bought a labjack, by the way.

Comment: @mkeith That helps! So if I use a 24 bit ADC (maybe a sigma delta converter) ,I would be able to get my values without any amplification since my values are in millivolt range right?

Comment: That is what Kartman is saying. I believe that it is true. There would be no point in making 24 bit ADC's if it was not possible to read them to at least 22 bits or so accurately. But I am sure you will have to pay attention to low-noise design techniques to make it work well. Calibration will probably be needed. This is true for op-amp design also, though.

Comment: What's the common mode voltage of your input signal, with respect to your 5V supply and ground? The HX711 is a widely available low cost sigma delta that will measure mV for you.

Comment: You need to set the gain for the largest signal, not the smallest. If you do a gain of 256 your 10mV signal will saturate.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to component availability in your area (Sri Lanka?) but there are many op-amps that will do this. Look for Auto-Zero or Zero-drift op-amps. You can easily get relatively high accuracy with a gain of 100 or so for 100mV to 1V out using a simple non-inverting amplifier configuration.

For example, [AD8551](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8551_8552_8554.pdf) which has a maximum Vos of 5uV and a maximum TCVos of 40nV/K. Voltage noise 0-10Hz is 1uVp-p so that should not limit the ADS1115 too much.

Comment: Does minimum full scale range imply that it is the lowest measurable voltage?. Or can we just think the resolution (step size) is the minimum detectable voltage if it fed to the input alone to a typical ADC. For an example 5V 16 bit would have a resolution of around 76uV. 1. Does it say it can measure the value of 76uV. 2 Or does it say after a lower threshold value it would show the values in that resolution. I mean if 76uV is detectable I don't have to use an amplifier in my case.

Comment: Resolution is full scale voltage (span) divided by 2^15, so for .256V it would be about 7.8uV. Noise may well be more than that, read the datasheet, and consider your operating conditions such as sample rate, and remember RMS noise is much lower than P-P.